# Git svn multiple projects one repo

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Currently my work uses svn, but i'm trying to bring git at least locally so we can branch stash etc. We share our svn repo with multiple teams, thus its quite large with many projects - we only ever checkout a handful of these projects and will forever ignore the rest. For the forseeable future, this is not going to change.

I've configured a workspace with git-svn, however i've needed to perform a git svn clone for every project we wanted (Cloning the entire repo is not an option), thus creating a separate local git repo for every project.. not ideal when it comes to branching.. I currently have 5 projects at the moment in my git svn workspace, each one is its own repo. Is there any way of making the parent directory of these local projects the "main" git repo, therefore when I commit/pull/rebase/branch, I just do it once and not individually for every project?

Has anyone found themselves in a similar situation? What have you done?

Thanks